# Is there a name for poems where each verse is a time period?

Tags: poetry, terminology

I'm having a hard time finding examples of this, but I found one by a man named Darryl Davis, called [Almanac of a man](https://www.poetrysoup.com/poem/almanac_of_a_man_423600), that goes like this:

> When I was five,
>   I was supreme ruler
>   of a boundless realm.
>   Hopes were high,
>  
>   supervision constant.
>  
>   Animals could speak,
>  
>   kisses could heal.
>
> When I was fifteen,
>  
>   ...
>
> When I was twenty-five,
>  
>   ...

etc.

I remember seeing this style on many occasions, in poetry and in pop songs, but I can't find a general discussion of this style or genre. Is there a term for this?

(...I just realized that [7 years](https://genius.com/Lukas-graham-7-years-lyrics) is a pretty recent pop example of this.)